# Keys.Space in selenium not working

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I have this code written in python2.7 and I'm using Firefox 52 and selenium 3.3

```
z = browser . find_element_by_class_name ('txtinput')

for x in y :

    z.send_keys (x)
    z.send_keys (Keys.SPACE)
    sleep (0.5)
```

Basically , this code just put letters in textbox ... The website's textbox will be empty/clear whenever I hit the 'space bar' but the above code is not working . It doesn't even giving errors ......

Example :

```
y = [ 'hello' , 'good' , 'love' ]
```

The textbox must be

```
textbox: hello
```

Then proceed to another value

```
textbox: good
```

And so on....

But Keys.SPACE doesn't seem to work ....

:-(

It looks like this :

```
textbox: hellogoodlove
```

Can anyone help me ?

I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you try just to replace `for` loop with `z.send_keys(" ".join(y))`?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't . I need to input them one by one .

Comment: Ok... And how about simple `z.send_keys (x + " ")`?

Comment: Ok . I'll try that.

Comment: @Andersson , Thank you very much ! It worked ! :-)))

Answer (score 0):

Just pass simple space

```
z.send_keys(' ')
```